# What is the closest utility to Snoop for iPhone/iPad development?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wpf, uikit, snoop

Is there anything remotely close to the [WPF Snoop utility](http://blois.us/Snoop/) for iPhone/iOS development?

I have found [Mike Ash's ObjC wrapper](https://github.com/mikeash/MAObjCRuntime), however this seems more helpful for reflection than for analyzing the instance state of UIKit hierarchies.

An example of where this is useful:  I integrated a split-view inside of a tabbar view and it's not quite working.  Yes there are some bits of code out there for this to just "make it work".  However I want to get dirty and fix my own problems to better master the platform.

The most obvious implementations seem to be to pass in a root viewcontroller instance to a utility class method.

The utility could then output the UIKit hierarchy in the debug window, or to get fancy, popup a modal view that lets you graphically browse the state like Snoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get your hands dirty, just leverage objective-C's dynamic behavior, and implement it yourself. You could create a category on UIView with a recursive method that prints out info about its children. Then in GDB just call it on the window (since window is a subclass of UIView. Something like:

```
@interface UIView ( DebugExras )
    - (void)debugPrintViewTree;
@end
```

And in GDB:

```
gdb: po [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] debugPrintViewTree]
```

Comment: Not really a solution, but you did answer my question with the current answer being "there is nothing like it", and also a reasonable suggestion for rolling your own.  Therefore I've marked it as the answer.

Comment: After receiving advice that there is nothing like Snoop for UIKit, I went the through the exercise of writing a basic graphical tree walker.  Unfortunately since I'm new I can't post the code within 24hrs, so I can just tell you it works in principle and is a helpful visual aid.